# Session object or Class for traking user seeeion

Tags: asp.net

to keep track of User session what is the best method either storing user session data in Session or by creating object of class user

Answer (score 1):

For Session related data, session is the best place. Even if you create a different object (say user), how shall you persist between page calls? You may create a class, but shall have to persist it in the session ultimaltely.

If you wish not to load session heavuly (which is recommended not to load the session too heavily), you may persist data in the database also. But the management of the data will have to be maintained by your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class that abstracts User and another class that abstracts the storage of the information - that way you could change it to be backed by a database later if you wanted to scale (use of Session should be minimised in any application).

ASP.NET has a built in [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) and [Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx) provider model which will help you with this task.